# Do you lose your augs halfway through like in the Director's Cut?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

I just started playing DXHR for the first time and I went for the Directors Cut version which has the DLC Missing Link segment spliced into it somewhere in the middle.

I got to the Missing Link part and lost all my augs and upgrades because you're supposed to begin that segment with nothing. Anyway, I wasn't a big fan of that (to put it mildly) because I spent a long time maximising my XP in the previous missions and getting those augs in the first place. Now, I've just finished the Missing Link part (really didn't enjoy it compared to the rest of the game but I digress) and my augs haven't come back.

Do I ever get my old aug levels back at any point? Does the standard version of DXHR also take away all your augs at the same point or is it just a product of the Missing Link bit?

I would've preferred a complete return to equilibrium at the end of the Missing Link part. I realise now that I went for the wrong version but it's too late to turn back now!

Comment: No you never lose your augs in the standard version of the game.  As for how to get them back, i don't know

Comment: Isn't there a box with all your gear and praxis kits right near the stasis pod exit? Sure, you'd have to redo your augs but that's the price you pay for getting caught ;)

Comment: @JC2k8 No, I only found 8 praxis kits in that box :(. It should've been closer to 60 by that point. I was only maybe a dozen points away from having all augs at max. Anyway, what really frustrated me about the whole experience was that I'd actually deliberately not used any praxis points during the Missing Link part in order to spend them afterwards when, I believed, I'd get the rest of my augs back. It made the whole section tedious and needlessly difficult for no good reason!

Comment: There is a lot of praxis to find in the area where you lose all the augs. It takes quite a bit of exploring to find some of them though.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you do get all your kit back at the end of the Missing Link.

> Once you've finished the DLC, Quinn has left a box with all your gear in it, next to a cryotube you use to continue your journey (relax, there is a mission-marker on the hud on top of it.)
>   (beware, I personally did not get back my old gear. but it might be because I already had an inventory full of stuff... so save before you open it. if you run into a similar problem, clear out your inventory. will edit this part when I find out what makes the box tick.)
>
> It is interesting to note that the Missing Link mission now acts as a mid-game respec... for those who regret the choices in augments that they did early in the game.

Source: http://www.ps3trophies.org/forum/deus-ex-human-revolution/214740-directors-cut-answers.html

Comment: It seems that you get your weapons back almost at the start of the missing link mission. And those weapons are later NOT INCLUDED in the big box Quinn gives you at the end. I was going for factory zero achievement, so did not take them at the start and ended up without weapons after leaving the platform.